# Trouble on Qt Creator on macOS - ld: library not found for -lQt5Widgets_debug

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, qt5

I installed Qt Creator 4.5.0 based on Qt5.10.0 and I made a simple project.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

I built this project and got this message.

```
ld: library not found for -lQt5Widgets_debug
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I use macOS10.13.2, Xcode9.2. What should I do for this?
I must install some libraries for this?

.pro is below.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test1
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
        widget.h

FORMS += \
        widget.ui
```

widget.h is below.

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp is below.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thank you for watching this.

Comment: show your .pro.

Comment: Thank you for watching the question. I added .pro above.

Comment: in main.cpp you are including `#include "widget.h"` ... what is widget.h ??

Comment: I added widget.h and widget.cpp. Please watch it.

Comment: How have you installed Qt5?

Comment: I installed Qt Creator Open Source ver from https://www.qt.io/download
I have deleted and reinstalled Qt Creator some times, is there any probrem?
Story changes but I installed anaconda3 and it includes pt5 pachage, is there any confliction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its likely that the files `widget.h` and `widget.cpp` do NOT exist in your project, which might cause this issue. and anyway your project is not using them.

In order to run the piece of code you written in `main.cpp` your project `.pro` need not be more than this:

```
  #-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-01-15T00:00:06
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test1
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \


HEADERS += \


FORMS += \
```

And remove `#include widget.h` from `main.cpp`  because you are not using widget.cpp and widget.h for anything.

Comment: I removed widget.cpp, widget.h and widget.ui from .pro. And I removed "#include "widget.h" from main.cpp. But I got the same error "ld: library not found for -lQt5Widgets_debug".
Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @Yoshiki.M , How did you install Qt? it seems you are missing libraries, can you show what kit is auto configured in qt? besides, check if qt is correctly built by reading my post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272668/cant-import-configure-qt-project/48273466#48273466