# Any kits not found on Qt creator 4.5 during projects creation

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I installed Qt creator 4.5 on  Windows 10. When I want to create a project, the application does not find any kit. 
I installed Mingw compiler and debuger and Cmake.

Comment: And Now? tell us more ..

Comment: I can't create project because there is not kit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import/configure Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272668/cant-import-configure-qt-project)

Comment: Follow Qt documentation to get a working `Kit`

Comment: I Will reinstall the app